# C# - Faster way to check if a directory and sub-directories contain at least 1 file from a list of allowed file extensions?

Tags: c#, file, directory

Part of my program involves validating 2 directories if both contain at least 1 file from a given list of allowed extensions.

```
if (DoesDirectoryHaveValidFiles(directory1) &&
    DoesDirectoryHaveValidFiles(directory2))
```

My current issue is that, given a directory tree that is deep enough, or having too much sub-directories, my current implementation takes too much time for what it does.

Can anyone give me some help how I can speed up my checking?

```
bool DoesDirectoryHaveValidFiles(string directory)
{
    var allowedExtensions = new string[] {".aaa", ".bbb", ".ccc"};
    var directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(directory);
    var fileInfos = directoryInfo.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                                 .Where(file => allowedExtensions.Any(file.FullName.ToLower().EndsWith));

    return fileInfos.Count() > 0;
}
```

Comment: Instead of `Where`, try using `Any`.

Comment: Since `GetFiles` returns a `FileInfo[]` you can use `file.Extension` instead of `file.FullName.ToLower().EndsWith`.

Comment: MSFT Says that EnumerateFiles is faster. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413232(v=vs.110).aspx. If performance is that important to you, it may be worth the time for benchmarking.

Comment: `var fileInfos = directoryInfo.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                                 .Where(file => allowedExtensions.Any(file.FullName.ToLower().EndsWith));

    return fileInfos.Count() > 0;` can be simplified to `return directoryInfo.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                                 .Any(file => allowedExtensions.Any(file.FullName.ToLower().EndsWith));` that way the method will return when one matching file is found rather than having to find all of them.

Comment: The correct replacement would be `fileInfos .Any(f => allowedExtensions.Any(a => a.Contains(f.Extension)))`.

Comment: @DourHighArch - Yes I was able to correctly put it a while ago, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** After **SBFrancies's** help for the `.Where` to `.Any`, and **Dour High Arch's** help for the `file.Extension`, I have replaced it with the following code, and I think it is now fast enough for what I need it to do.

*But* if you guys have other comments about my implementation, please dont hesitate to inform me, as Im still learning with regards to these parts.

```
bool DoesDirectoryHaveValidFiles(string directory)
{
    var allowedExtensions = new string[] {".aaa", ".bbb", ".ccc"};
    var directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(directory);
    var hasValidFiles = directoryInfo.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                                     .Any(file => allowedFileExtensions.Contains(file.Extension));

    return hasValidFiles;
}
```